# Property [date] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to pass date in my blade view from an eloquent relationship but getting the above error. I have been unable to find questions similar to this case. Here's what i have done so far, I have the following models

Product

```
class Product extends Model
{
protected $guarded = ['id'];

public function prices()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Price::class, 'product_id');
}
}
```

Price

```
class Price extends Model
{
protected $guarded = ['id'];

public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_id');
}
}
```

I'm passing data in my controller like this

```
public function index()
{
$products = Product::with('prices')->orderBy('id')->get();

$prices = Price::all()->groupBy('date');

return view('home', compact('products', 'prices'));
}
```

And my this is the code for my view

```
@foreach($prices as $price)
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        {{ $price->date }}
    </div>

    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Difference</th>
                <th>Percentage</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            @foreach($price->product as $product)    
                <td>{{ $product->name }}</td>
            @endforeach
                <td>{{ $price->cost }}</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
@endforeach
```

What have i missed and how do i get my code to work?

Comment: Do you have date attribute for your Price model?

Comment: Yes i do, the prices table columns are id, product_id, date and cost

Answer (score 0):

Update date attribute name to date_product for example.
Let's me know if it works :)

Comment: `(2/2) ErrorException

Property [created_at] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: E:\wamp64\www\ndcl\resources\views\home.blade.php)`

Comment: Do you have this line in your Price_migration file ? 
$table->timestamps();
Or : does Prices tables have created_at and updated_at attributes ?

Comment: Yes I do. I'm simply calling $price->created_at instead of the date, rather than change the column name. This is the result of the dumped $prices if it would help `Collection {#213 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    "2017-08-04" => Collection {#207 ▼
      #items: array:3 [▼
        0 => Price {#235 ▶}
        1 => Price {#236 ▶}
        2 => Price {#237 ▶}
      ]
    }
    "2017-08-07" => Collection {#206 ▶}
    "2017-08-08" => Collection {#214 ▶}
  ]
}`